# Clear message after reloading page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my codeigniter login controller I have this code below

```
$session_userdata_token = $this->session->userdata('token');
$input_token = $this->uri->segment(2);

if (!isset($session_userdata_token) && isset($input_token)) {
  $this->error['warning'] = 'Your session has expired!';
}
```

If the session expires it redirects to login controller with token in url like

```
http://localhost/cookie/login/0cY9WNUvodIhBrJi
```

Then the warning message will show up OK. But once the message shows up and I reload page I would like message to clear even though token in url.

> **My question** is once the warning message shows up and then I reload
>   page how to clear the message using code above?
>
> **Note please read:** Do not want to use flashdata because it creates extra files in codeigniter 3 versions when use `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';`

Comment: So you want to execute the same code if the user reloads the page but don't want to display the warning again?

Comment: @GustavoRubio Once the message has shown then if user decided to reload page I would like the message cleared..

Comment: you can use flashdata if you want to only for temp purpose.

Comment: Can we know why you don't want to use flashdata?

Comment: @GustavoRubio Just prefer to have less session if possible

Comment: Well how would you know that that particular user has already seen the message if you don't hook it to a session? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the warning message using jquery set timeout function. Let the message be displayed for desired number of seconds and after that remove it.

Answer (score 0):

CI has:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('somename','data');
```

you can use it by

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('somename');
```

Flash data always cleared after a redirect.

You can alos tempdata:

```
$this->session->set_tempdata('success', 'Message', 10); # 10 means secods
echo $this->session->tempdata('success');
```

After 10 seconds it will be removed

You can use HTML5 browser storage:

if you want to set it from controller you can use:

```
echo "<script> localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red')</script>";
```

To set:

```
 localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red');
```

To get:

```
 localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
```

To Remove:

```
localStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```

Comment: The reason I do not want to use flash data as said in question is because the codeigniter 3 versions creates extra files for that when using files `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';`

Comment: Is that a sensitive data?

If normal data, you can use HTML5 LocalStorage.

 localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red');
you can get by  localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');